# Use case for std::promise::set_{value|exception}_at_thread_exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise, future

When do I *have to* use [`std::promise::set_value_at_thread_exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_value_at_thread_exit)/[`std::promise::set_exception_at_thread_exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_exception_at_thread_exit) over [`std::promise::set_value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_value)/[`std::promise::set_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_exception)?

The only difference is that the former are guaranteed to make the associated future ready only once `thread_local`s of the calling thread have been destroyed. However I can't think of any non-synthetic example where this would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

One thing could be to know if a detached thread has finished running, when your program is still in a state where it cares to know.